# Send an image from Android imagevview to server by Post request

Tags: php, android, image, post

I'm trying to send an image I uploaded to an imageview in an android application to a server to be uploaded there. I've read a few tutorials here and there but what I have tried isn't working though so it might be due to the way the server handles pictures.

Well here is the code of how I get the picture to the imageview in android

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.yprofilepic);
            image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);           
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);
            byte [] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
            image_str = Base64.encodeBytes(byte_arr);

}
```

This is how pictures are received on my server before being uploaded.

```
public function upload_picture(){
            $picture = (isset($_POST["picture"])) ? $_POST["picture"] : "";

             $picture = "";

                if(isset($_FILES) && isset($_FILES["picture"]))
                {
                    $picture_file = $_FILES["picture"];
                    if($picture_file["size"] > 0 && !empty($picture_file["name"]))
                    {
                        $extension = explode(".", $picture_file["name"]);
                        $extension = $extension[sizeof($extension)-1];
                        $file_extensions = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'bmp', 'png');
                        if(in_array($extension, $file_extensions))
                        {
                            $new_file = "assets/uploads/".md5(time().rand(0, 1000).$email).".".$extension;
                            if (move_uploaded_file($picture_file['tmp_name'], $new_file)) {
                                $image = new Image_Library();
                                $image->load($new_file);
                                $image->resizeToWidth(150);
                                $image->resizeToHeight(150);
                                $image->save($new_file);
                                $picture = SITE_ROOT.$new_file;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                $model = new Users_Model();
                $status = $model->upload_picture($user_id, $picture);
                $response = array("operation" => $status);
                return new JSON($response);

            }
```

I don't know what is the best way to send the image from android to the server with a POST Request.

EDIT 
I actually used the coderzheaven method and it didn't work. This is how I implemented it.

```
class uploadPic extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("This is the string for the picture "+image_str);
            List<NameValuePair> p=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            p.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",user));
            JSONObject js=jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_id, "POST", p);

                 ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new  ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("picture",image_str));
            try {
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", js.getString("user_id")));
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            JSONObject j=jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(upload_pic, "POST", nameValuePairs);
            Log.d("Picture status", j.toString());
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/04/25/android-upload-an-image-to-a-server/

Comment: Test your Server with Postman and then Check if issue is in Android or server Code.

Answer (score 0):

I think a good option is to send the base 64 encoded string for the image, not the image file. This way you can sent the POST request and save the file in the server.

Comment: Check the edit. I implemented it that way but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you the steps but you have to try exact code for it

**STEPS**

1) retrieve bitmap object from your ImageView (use method iv.getDrawingCache())

2) get your byte[] from that bitmap object

3) convert bytes into base64string as follow
    (*i.e* **String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, 0);** )

4) pass this base64string as parameter to webservice.

thats it